# JavaScript and HTML : in two separate files or in a single HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, compilation, browserify

Is there any difference when we write both `HTML` and `JavaScript` code in a single `.html` file or write `HTML` code in a `.html` file and `JavaScript` in a `.js` file separately ? I mean functionality in both cases is the same ?

ex. here : https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard `HTML` and `JavaScript` are written in two separate `.html` and `.js` files and in top of `.js` file is mentioned: **NOTE: Need to compile with browserify viz.js -o main.js** .

I mean if `JavaScript` code in `viz.js` file is written in `index.html` file, do we still need to use `browserify` to compile `JavaScript` code ?

`index.html` file : https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard/blob/master/index.html

`viz.js` file : https://github.com/tomconte/solarchain-dashboard/blob/master/viz.js

Comment: Modularizing code has many benefits for the programmer. But, modularization of JS is not supported by default in the browser. That is where Browserify and Webpack come in. They take modularized code and compile to a single JS file.

Answer (score 5):

To *in two separate files or in a single HTML file?*

No difference.

Just browser has to send an extra `http` request to load the file when you add `js` file in `<script>` tag.

But it is a good practice to write your code in separate js file, so it would be easy to modify it and reflect those changes in all the `html` files wherever that js file is linked otherwise you'll have to change js code in every file etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the javascript separately in a file will improve page load performance. Inlining the javascript inside the html file can block rendering of html.

In the inline script, the time is taken up running the script, which might change the DOM. Trying to render the DOM while it's mutating is a recipe for a mess. So rendering only happens at points when the JS is stalled, and therefore the DOM is stable.

While waiting for an external script to download, the running of scripts is stalled, so the DOM can be rendered safely. The downloaded JS won't be run until the rendering is complete.

So this is one reason the files html files are separated from javascript files.

Also maintenance of Javascript in files will be easier than embedded in html.